# Filter value causes query to fail

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We have an interesting table query (SQL Server 2008) that fails with a different field value. Has anyone seen this before?

This runs fine (500ms)

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StatisticNo asc) AS RowId, Statistics.* 
FROM Statistics 
WHERE myear = 2010
```

This completes after a long time (>3 mins)

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StatisticNo asc) AS RowId, Statistics.* 
FROM Statistics 
WHERE myear = 2011
```

The table contains data for both 2010 and 2011. Interestingly enough it runs fine as well for 2012 as a filter option which is currently an empty set. We checked for normalized problems and there is no missing or null data. The myear field is a required numeric.

There are no open or active locks on the table.  It is a statistics table that is written to once a day.

Comment: Run `DBCC OPENTRAN dbname` to see if you have any open transactions.

Comment: Do you have any records where `myear=2011`?

Comment: What happens if you run `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` before each query?? How do the times stack up now??

Comment: @Ardman - The OPENTRAN didn't reveal any open transactions related to this data.  @Lazurus Yes there is data.  @Marc_s  Tried it with no improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have an open transaction locking a `2011` row. Try using the `NOLOCK` hint to confirm this.

If that returns results without being blocked then you can find the culprit spid by running again without the hint then looking in `sys.dm_tran_locks` whilst the blocking is occurring.

Comment: No open transactions are locking.  There was no change in query performance when using NOLOCK.

Comment: @jarofclay I see the description has now changed from "never completes (>20mins)" to "This completes after a long time (>3 mins)" Why is that? Has it improved? In any event can you post the plans for both? Also what is the definition of the `Statistics` table?  And what figures do you get if you try `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and  `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`?

Comment: The STATISTICS IO ON helped dramatically.  Thank you.

Comment: @jarofclay - That must just be coincidence, the only effect that setting this option has is that it reports the IO stats for your queries (I was wondering if they were dramatically increased for the `2011` query for whatever reason)

Answer (score 2):

Could you please run this query:

```
SELECT  year, COUNT(*)
FROM    statistics
GROUP BY
        year
```

If you have few records in `2010` and `2012` but lots of records in `2011`, then it would be perfectly normal for the query to run longer.

Comment: There are less records in 2011 (161) than in 2010 (1896) (and no records in 2012).

Comment: @jarofclay: could you please post the execution plans for both queries? `3 minutes` for `161` records certainly rings the bell. Is it reproducible?